# Fragment not restoring edittext value after swapping back in view_pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

**first fragment not restoring edit box value after swapping 3 fragment  in viewPager...  i have  3 fragment inside viewpager and after clicking on 3rd fragment tab and swap back to 1st fragment .. edit text filling blank.. plz give some solutions.. code is here..**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_master, container, false);
    viewPager = (ViewPager)v. findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout)v. findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    return  v;
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
   // ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager());
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new ItemInfoFragment(), "Item Info");
    adapter.addFragment(new ItemExtraInfoFragment(), "Extra Info");
    adapter.addFragment(new OrderHistoryFragment(), "Order History");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}



    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
            private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
            private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

            public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
                super(manager);
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                return mFragmentList.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return mFragmentList.size();
            }

            public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
                mFragmentList.add(fragment);
                mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
            }
```

Comment: try strong the value in some persistence data type to use them when fragment loads , your problem will be solved

Comment: ViewPager only keeps fragment which is currently displayed, plus two fragments to the left and to the right of the current one. If your fragment went past this point, it is removed. So yes, you need some persistent storage to store your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is recommended only if you have less number of fragments. 
You can use `yourViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(numberOfFragmentsInViewPager);`
What this does is it wont create a new fragment every time you swipe, thus data is persisted. the default value will be 1 if you won't set this property.